# Очередь выполнения в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы, очередь-задач

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

    // Queue
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 0);

    // i < 5; Execution stack ended

    // Queue => execution происходит здесь? Не за телом цикла
    console.log(i) // 5,5,5,5,5

}

//Queue => execution
i = 5
console.log(i) // 5
```

Comment: что почему? var делает переменную видимой глобально

Comment: чтобы избежать этого, надо юзать let или const

Comment: Потому что в после каждой итерации происходит увеличение переменной и только потом сравнение?

Comment: почему она равна пяти за телом цикла? Откуда значение?

Comment: @user275011 я тебе написал 2 минуты назад

Comment: 4 меньше 5? Тело цикла выполняется, затем идет инкремент и вот тебе 5 получается

Comment: А чему еще может быть равна переменная i после окончания цикла?

Comment: @0xdb возможно, автор ожидал, что `i++` не станет выполняться, если это сделает условие ложным — вполне возможная ситуация для новичков, не до конца понимающих принципы, по которым выполняется код, я сам так же тупил восемь лет назад)

Comment: До правки вопрос дубликатом не был, а после правки дубликатом стал, хех

Comment: @andreymal потому что до правки и после правки - это 2 совершенно разных вопроса

Comment: Запутался, да [15 символов]

Answer (score 2):

Для начала отметим, что область действия `var` — вся функция (или иное пространство имён). Можно считать, что при выполнении кода все `var` неявно перемещаются в начало:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {}
```

Теперь про цикл `for`. Он состоит из трёх частей (не считая тела):

```
for (начало; условие; шаг) {тело}
```

В начале выполняется `начало`, потом проверяется `условие`; если оно истинно, выполняется `тело` цикла и затем выполняется `шаг`. Потом снова проверяется условие; если оно истинно, снова выполняется тело цикла и шаг; и так далее, пока условие не станет ложно.

Вот давайте так и разберём ваш цикл по шагам:

- начало: делаем `i` равным 0
- проверяем условие: `0 < 5`, условие истинно, выполняем тело цикла
- выполняем шаг `i++`; теперь `i` равно 1
- проверяем условие: `1 < 5`, условие истинно, выполняем тело цикла
- выполняем шаг `i++`; теперь `i` равно 2
- проверяем условие: `2 < 5`, условие истинно, выполняем тело цикла
- выполняем шаг `i++`; теперь `i` равно 3
- проверяем условие: `3 < 5`, условие истинно, выполняем тело цикла
- выполняем шаг `i++`; теперь `i` равно 4
- проверяем условие: `4 < 5`, условие истинно, выполняем тело цикла
- выполняем шаг `i++`; теперь `i` равно 5
- проверяем условие: `5 < 5` — условие ложно! Ничего не выполняем, выходим из цикла
- два шага назад `i` стал равен 5, поэтому `console.log(i)` выведет именно 5.

Функция в `setTimeout` даже с нулевой задержкой выполняется не сразу, а после того, как весь другой код завершился. В процессе выполнения цикла ваш код ещё не завершился (ваш код это работающий цикл, ага), поэтому во время выполнения вышеописанных шагов никакой `setTimeout` ещё не срабатывает.

Последняя строчка в вашем коде — `console.log`; после неё код завершается. И только тогда начинают запускаться все отложенные `setTimeout`ы! Но к этому времени цикл ведь уже выполнился и переменная `i` осталась равна 5 — именно поэтому вы в результате получите пять (или даже шесть с учётом последнего log) чисел 5 в консоли.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно использовать `let`, который, в отличие от `var`, действует только в пределах текущей итерации цикла и не существует за его пределами (работает только в новых браузерах):

```js
console.log('Цикл начат');
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 0);
}
console.log('Цикл завершён, сейчас будут setTimeoutы');
```

Или можно обернуть `setTimeout` в функцию и создать в ней новую переменную в виде аргумента функции, которая будет действовать только в пределах этой функции (работает и в старых браузерах):

```js
console.log('Цикл начат');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i_local) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i_local);
        }, 0);
    })(i);  // вызываем анонимную функцию, передавая i в аргументе
}

console.log('Цикл завершён с i = ' + i + ', сейчас пойдут setTimeoutы');
```

Answer (score 0):

Наглядно разницу между `var` и `let` можно посмотреть на следующем примере:

```js
console.log(a); //undefined
var a = 5;
console.log(a) //5
```

```js
console.log(a); //Тут же выдаст ошибку a is not defined
let a = 5;
console.log(a);
```

Поэтому в циклах, как и пишут в комментариях, рекомендуется использовать `let`.

Comment: А причем здесь Hoisting вообще?